# Android Resource Scaling For 4.65" and 4.7" Emulator Not Correct

Tags: android, xml, resources, emulation, scaling

I have layout xml files for default, default-land, sw480dp, sw480dp-land,sw600dp, and sw600dp-land in an Android project I'm working on. All emulator's scale my resources correctly except for the 4.65" and 4.7" emulators in Eclipse, and does not scale the ad space, or my buttons correctly. These emulators seem to be pulling my default layout resources, but the scaling is wayyy off, and I am not sure why this is. I've tried adding a new folder for sw720dp, but this pulls up the 10" tablet emulator, and does not allow the 4.65 or 4.7 inch devices. Can anyone give me some clues as to what might be going wrong here? I'm done with all my functionality, and was just testing out all devices before submitting the app, and now I've hit a road block. Thanks!

P.S

Not sure what kind of info you'd need to help me out with this, code wise, so let me know what  might help you, and I'll insert it!

Comment: what is the resolution of your emulators?

Comment: What's up FoamyGuy! I have actually figured this one out. I had to create layout files for sw360dp, and sw360dp-land. This cleared it all up!